# How to embed javascript code directly in scala.js?

Tags: javascript, scala.js

When I use scala.js to write scala code to generate javascript, I found it difficult sometimes to wrap the 3rd-party javascript code into scala objects.

Is there anyway to embed some javascript code directly? e.g. as strings?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

No, there isn't, on purpose. How would identifiers in the "embedded" JavaScript code bind to identifiers in the surrounding Scala.js code, for example? That would never make any sense.

### The ugly workaround: `js.eval`

You can "embed" JavaScript code as a parameter to the [`js.eval`](http://www.scala-js.org/api/scalajs-library/0.6.0/index.html#scala.scalajs.js.package@eval%28x:String%29:scala.scalajs.js.Any) function, obviously.

```
import scala.scalajs.js

def foo(x: Int): Unit =
  js.eval("console.error('hello');")
```

But `js.eval` always evaluates in the global scope (not in the scope where you call it), so this doesn't work:

```
def foo(x: Int): Unit =
  js.eval("console.error(x);") // x undefined here
```

### The good solution: `js.Dynamic`

Although you cannot embed arbitrary JavaScript code in Scala.js code, you can use [`js.Dynamic`](http://www.scala-js.org/api/scalajs-library/0.6.0/index.html#scala.scalajs.js.Dynamic) and [`js.DynamicImplicits`](http://www.scala-js.org/api/scalajs-library/0.6.0/index.html#scala.scalajs.js.DynamicImplicits$). With those, you can typically transliterate JavaScript code directly into Scala syntax (which is very close to JS syntax) with the "JavaScript semantics":

```
import scala.scalajs.js
import js.DynamicImplicits._
import js.Dynamic.{global => g}

def foo(x: Int): Unit =
  g.console.error(x)
```

You can even write crazy JavaScript-ish code like this:

```
if (g.console)
  (g.console.error || g.console.log).call(g.console, x)
```

if you want to be robust against `console` or `console.error` not existing, for example.

The advantage of this approach is that normal binding rules for identifiers. And you don't have to resort to strings to get the job done.