# How to invoke nodejs modules from scala.js?

Tags: node.js, scala.js

I'm trying to use scala.js + [nw.js](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js) to write some application, and will use some node modules in scala.js. But I'm not sure how to do it.

Say, there is module `fs` and I can write such code in Javascript:

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.writeFile("/tmp/test", "Hey there!", function(err) {
    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log("The file was saved!");
    }
});
```

But how to do the same in scala.js from scratch?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using [`js.Dynamic`](http://www.scala-js.org/api/scalajs-library/0.6.0/index.html#scala.scalajs.js.Dynamic) and [`js.DynamicImplits`](http://www.scala-js.org/api/scalajs-library/0.6.0/index.html#scala.scalajs.js.DynamicImplicits$) (see also [a longer answer on the topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28656170/how-to-embed-javascript-code-directly-in-scala-js)), you can transliterate your code in Scala.js:

```
import scala.scalajs.js
import js.Dynamic.{global => g}
import js.DynamicImplicits._

val fs = g.require("fs")
fs.writeFile("/tmp/test", "Hey there!", { (err: js.Dynamic) =>
  if (err)
    console.log(err)
  else
    console.log("The file was saved!")
})
```

You can find a longer source code using the Node.js `fs` module in Scala.js here:
https://github.com/scala-js/scala-js/blob/v0.6.0/tools/js/src/main/scala/org/scalajs/core/tools/io/NodeVirtualFiles.scala

Comment: Shouldn't it be `g.require("fs")`?