# How to provide and consume require.js modules in scala.js (and extending classes)

Tags: node.js, requirejs, atom-editor, scala.js

I'm doing this Ensime package for Atom.io https://github.com/ensime/ensime-atom and I've been thinking about the possibility to use scala.js instead of writing Coffeescript.

Atom is a web based editor which is scripted with js and is node.js based. A plugin/package defines it's main entry point by pointing out a javascript object with a few specific.

I figured I should start out simple and try using scala.js replacing the simplest coffeescript file I have:

```js
{View} = require 'atom-space-pen-views'
# View for the little status messages down there where messages from Ensime server can be shown
module.exports =
  class StatusbarView extends View
    @content: ->
      @div class: 'ensime-status inline-block'

    initialize: ->

    serialize: ->

    init: ->
      @attach()

    attach: =>
      statusbar = document.querySelector('status-bar')
      statusbar?.addLeftTile {item: this}

    setText: (text) =>
      @text("Ensime: #{text}").show()

    destroy: ->
      @detach()
```

As you can see this exports a require.js module and is a class extending a class fetched with require as well.

Sooo.

I'm thinking I'd just use Dynamic for the require dep as I've seen on SO [How to invoke nodejs modules from scala.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28656343/how-to-invoke-nodejs-modules-from-scala-js):

```scala
import js.Dynamic.{global => g}
import js.DynamicImplicits._

private[views] object SpacePen {
  private val spacePenViews = require("atom-space-pen-views")
  val view = spacePenViews.view
}
```

But if I wanted to type the super-class, could I just make a facade-trait and do asInstanceOf?

Secondly, I wonder how I can export my class as a node module. I found this:

https://github.com/rockymadden/scala-node/blob/master/main/src/main/coffeescript/example.coffee

Is this the right way? Do I need to do the sandboxing? Couldn't I just get `module`imported from global and write `module.exports = _some_scala_object_`?

I'm also wondering how I could extend existing js classes. The same problem as asked here, but I don't really understand the answer:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scala-js/l0gSOSiqubs

```
My code so far:
```

```scala
private[views] object SpacePen {
  private val spacePenViews = js.Dynamic.global.require("atom-space-pen-views")
  type View = spacePenViews.view
}

class StatusBarView extends SpacePen.View  {
  override def content =
    super.div()

}
```

gives me compile errors that I can't extend sealed trait Dynamic. Of course.

Any pointers highly appreciated!

Comment: Hi Victor, I it sounds like you have two separate questions, right? I think your chance of getting them answered will be better if you split them into to SO posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not particularly expert in Node per se, but to answer your first question, yes -- if you have a pointer to a JS object, and you know the details of its type, you can pretty much always define a facade trait and asInstanceOf to use it. That ought to work.

As for the last bit, you basically can't extend JS classes in Scala.js -- it just doesn't work. The way most of us get around that is by defining implicit classes, or using implicit def's, to get the *appearance* of extending without actually doing so.

For example, given JS class Foo, I can write

    `implicit class RichFoo(foo:Foo) {
      def method1() = { ... }
    }`

This is actually a wrapper *around* Foo, but calling code can simply call foo.method1() without worrying about that detail.

You can see this approach in action very heavily in [jquery-facade](https://github.com/jducoeur/jquery-facade), particularly in the relationship between [JQuery](https://github.com/jducoeur/jquery-facade/blob/master/src/main/scala/org/querki/jquery/JQuery.scala) (the pure facade), [JQueryTyped](https://github.com/jducoeur/jquery-facade/blob/master/src/main/scala/org/querki/jquery/JQueryTyped.scala) (some tweaked methods over JQuery to make them work better in Scala), and [JQueryExtensions](https://github.com/jducoeur/jquery-facade/blob/master/src/main/scala/org/querki/jquery/JQueryExtensions.scala) (some higher-level functions built around JQuery).  These are held together using implicit def's in `package.scala`. As far as calling code is concerned, all of these simply look like methods on JQuery.

Comment: And since I answered this yesterday, things have updated slightly: there is [a new proposal to allow you to extend JS classes in Scala.js](https://github.com/scala-js/scala-js/issues/1795).  Mind, this is just a proposal at this stage, but it is specifically looking for commentary now.  So while this can't be done currently, it *may* be possible in the future.